# xhtml doesn't see <pre><code> as text

Tags: html, xhtml, epub

I have a problem, I want to write an epub book. I see it uses xhtml. I want to make something like the stackoverflow code block. Here is my CSS code:

```
pre{
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.5em;
background: #EEE;
padding: .75em;
margin: 1.5em 0 1.5em 0;
font-family: "Courier New",Courier,monospace;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666;
}
```

And my HTML code:

```
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

I tried using it with "quotation marks" and with 'apostrophes', but Sigil, which I am currently using sees it as an HTML code and gives me errors.

Please help me.

Comment: You should use the `<code>` tag instead of the `<pre>` tag. It won't solve you problem, but it's better suited for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the `<` inside the "code block" as `&lt;`. Or you might be able to enclode the code block in a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block.

Comment: It worked fine for me, thanks! specially if I put a <pre> tag before that CDATA